# Need help adding an Apex Class to a visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, salesforce1-app, code

Ok, so I need to add an apex class to a Visualforce page so that the page can have an extension to make it more functional but unfortunately, These are the only options on the Develop Menu.

- API
- Components
- Custom Settings
- Email Services
- Lightning Components BETA
- Pages
- Static Resources
- Remote Access

I just wanna ask, are there any alternatives?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What edition of Salesforce are you on? Seems like it might be Professional Edition, which does not include Apex support.

Answer (score 0):

Professional Edition

I was told to make an application with if else statements.

example,

initially the radio buttons are disabled and the word on the button is "save" if the save button is clicked, the word on the save button will become the word edit and all radio buttons will be enabled and clickable and vice versa